# Using js regex to replace simple markup styles like **bold** to <b>bold</b>

Tags: javascript, regex, text

I'm trying to take a chunk of plain text and convert parts of it into html tags. I don't need a full rich editor, just these few tags:

```
**bold**
__underline__
~~italics~~
--strike--
<<http://www.link.com>>
```

This is the method I have attempted to write but my lack of regex/js seems to be holding it back:

```
function toMarkup($this) {
    var text = $this.text();
    text = text.replace("\*\*(.*)\*\*", "<b>$1</b>");
    text = text.replace("__(.*)__", "<u>$1</u>");
    text = text.replace("~~(.*)~~", "<i>$1</i>");
    text = text.replace("--(.*)--", "<del>$1</del>");
    text = text.replace("<<(.*)>>", "<a href='$1'>Link</a>");
    $this.html(text);
}
```

Any glaring errors as to why these replaces are not working? Another issue I'm just now realizing is by converting this text to html I am unescaping any other potential tags that may be malicious. A bonus would be any advice on how to only escape these elements and nothing else.

Comment: _"Any glaring errors as to why these replaces are not working"_. Yes, because those are not regex, just strings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, they are just string, not regexs. Secondly you should use not-greedy `.*`.

Also, you may want to use the `g` modifier to match every occourrence in the text.

```
function toMarkup($this) {
    var text = $this.text();
    text = text.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
    text = text.replace(/__(.*?)__/g, "<u>$1</u>");
    text = text.replace(/~~(.*?)~~/g, "<i>$1</i>");
    text = text.replace(/--(.*?)--/g, "<del>$1</del>");
    text = text.replace(/<<(.*?)>>/g, "<a href='$1'>Link</a>");
    $this.html(text);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the `?` to your first regex to make it lazy too.

Comment: Thank you I didn't even notice the difference

Comment: This does not allow for `**S***` which should be `<strong>S*</strong>`

Comment: @T.Woody If it's necessary you can use `/\*\*(\**.*?\**)\*\*/`, not so readable though. The best regex for this would actually be: `/\*\*(\**[\s\S]*?\**)\*\*/g`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regexp object as the first argument to `text.replace()` instead of a string:

```
function toMarkup($this) {
    var text = $this.text();
    text = text.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
    text = text.replace(/__(.*?)__/g, "<u>$1</u>");
    text = text.replace(/~~(.*?)~~/g, "<i>$1</i>");
    text = text.replace(/--(.*?)--/g, "<del>$1</del>");
    text = text.replace(/<<(.*?)>>/g, "<a href='$1'>Link</a>");
    $this.html(text);
}
```

Note that I also replaced all of the `.*` with `.*?` which will match as few characters as possible, otherwise your matches may be too long.  For example you would match from the first `**` to the very last `**` instead of stopping at the next one.  The regex also needs the `g` flag so that all matches will be replaced (thanks Aaron).

Comment: don't forget the /g modifier on those regexes.

Answer (score -1):

```
 function toMarkup($this) {
   $this.html ($this.text ().replace (/(__|~~|--|\*\*)(.*?)\1|<<(.*?)>>\/g, 
     function (m, m1, m2, m3) {
       m[1] = {'**' : 'b>', '__': 'u>', '--': 'del>', '~~': 'i>'}[m[1]];
       return m[3] ? '<a href="' + m[3] + '">Link</a>'
                   : ('<' + m[1] + m[2] + '</' + m[1]);
     });
   }
```

Note that you cannot nest these, i.e. if you say `__--abc--__` will be converted to `<u>--abc--</u>`.